# Manter gif por um tempo depois de retirar o mouse

Tags: javascript, html

Bom dia, o meu problema é o seguinte: tenho um gif de um bulbasaur e quero que quando eu passar o mouse em cima dele o gif mude para outro, porém quando acabar a animação do 2° gif eu quero que ele volte automaticamente para o 1°, tem como fazer isso já que o gif fica reiniciando sozinho?

Meu código:

```
    <style> 
        img{
            width: 6%
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
   <img src="Bulbasaur_XY.gif" id="i"> 

   <script>
       var imagem = document.getElementById('i')
       imagem.addEventListener('mouseenter', entrar)
       imagem.addEventListener('mouseout',sair)

       function entrar(){
        document.getElementById('i').src="Bulbasaur_XY_AttackAnimation_Sprite (1).gif"
       }
       function sair(){
        document.getElementById('i').src="Bulbasaur_XY.gif"
       }
   </script>
</body>
```

Link com os gifs: 
1° gif = https://vignette.wikia.nocookie.net/pokemon/images/0/00/Bulbasaur_XY.gif/revision/latest?cb=20140319081443

2° gif = https://vignette.wikia.nocookie.net/pokemon/images/1/11/Bulbasaur_XY_AttackAnimation_Sprite.gif/revision/latest?cb=20141114181732

Também queria saber se tem como o 2 gif ficar do msm tamanho, já que o com primeiro e largura de cada um é diferente e eu estou usando a msm tag img.

Comment: Daniel, faltam algumas informações na sua pergunta. O que acontece se o mouse sair do elemento no meio da execução do 2º GIF? E se o mouse ficar repetidamente entrando e saindo do elemento?

Comment: @Daniel Lucas Sobre o tamanho da imagem esse artigo: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_img_width.asp

Comment: @fernandosavio o que eu quero é que quando o mouse passar no elemento 1 ele vá para o elemento 2, só que até o término da animação do elemento 2 os eventos do mouse fiquem impossibilitados de acontecer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Para ser bem sincero, não sei se é possível identificar o período de animação de um `gif`. Gostaria que a galera mais experiente da comunidade abordasse este assunto.

E outra coisa... Acredito que para manter um padrão visual em sua página as imagens devem possuir o mesmo tamanho e mesmo tempo de animação. E a partir desses dois critérios é possível utilizar uma função simples como o `setTimeout`.

> Veja como a diferença de tamanho entre as imagens e o tempo de animação influenciam no resultado final

```js
const pokemons = document.getElementsByClassName('pokemon');

function animatedPokemon() {
  const image = this;
  const src = image.dataset.src;
  const dataHover = image.dataset.hover;
  image.src = dataHover;

  setTimeout(function() {
    image.src = src
  }, 1900);
}

for (let i = 0; i < pokemons.length; i++) {
  pokemons[i].addEventListener('mouseover', animatedPokemon);
};
```

```css
img {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<img class="pokemon" src="https://vignette.wikia.nocookie.net/pokemon/images/0/00/Bulbasaur_XY.gif/revision/latest?cb=20140319081443" data-src="https://vignette.wikia.nocookie.net/pokemon/images/0/00/Bulbasaur_XY.gif/revision/latest?cb=20140319081443"
  data-hover="https://vignette.wikia.nocookie.net/pokemon/images/1/11/Bulbasaur_XY_AttackAnimation_Sprite.gif/revision/latest?cb=20141114181732">

<img class="pokemon" src="https://www.pkparaiso.com/imagenes/xy/sprites/animados/abra-2.gif" data-src="https://www.pkparaiso.com/imagenes/xy/sprites/animados/abra-2.gif" data-hover="https://images-wixmp-ed30a86b8c4ca887773594c2.wixmp.com/f/23ddfd0a-6934-4f06-9fa9-8be687766403/d81zxe8-ef67d1cf-fddc-4c62-9e61-13af794d876d.gif?token=eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJzdWIiOiJ1cm46YXBwOjdlMGQxODg5ODIyNjQzNzNhNWYwZDQxNWVhMGQyNmUwIiwiaXNzIjoidXJuOmFwcDo3ZTBkMTg4OTgyMjY0MzczYTVmMGQ0MTVlYTBkMjZlMCIsIm9iaiI6W1t7InBhdGgiOiJcL2ZcLzIzZGRmZDBhLTY5MzQtNGYwNi05ZmE5LThiZTY4Nzc2NjQwM1wvZDgxenhlOC1lZjY3ZDFjZi1mZGRjLTRjNjItOWU2MS0xM2FmNzk0ZDg3NmQuZ2lmIn1dXSwiYXVkIjpbInVybjpzZXJ2aWNlOmZpbGUuZG93bmxvYWQiXX0.O17RaDSNgsm86-CK5mxNkkeUkyrygiyF0uOyz_rdwas">
```

Comment: Aaaa obrigado dmais, rodei mt atrás de uma função ou algo assim mas só achei algumas coisas em java e n em javascript, você sabe se tem algum programa que ajuste a largura e a altura desses gifs pra ficarem iguais ?

Comment: Eu não sei quase nada sobre manipulação de imagens... Vou tentar achar alguma coisa e te falo :)

Comment: Blz, obrigado mais uma vez :)

Comment: você pode me explicar o que é esse 1900 no : setTimeout(function() {
    image.src = src
  }, 1900);  }? não entendi direito pra que ele serve

Comment: Claro. A função `setTimeout` executa a função passado no primeiro parâmetro após o tempo (em milissegundos) que foi definido no segundo parâmetro, ou seja, o número `1900` é a quantidade de tempo que a função "esperará" para ser executada. Então, caso o seu gif tenha uma duração total de 2 segundos até que comece a repetir novamente, você pode mudar o valor para `2000` milissegundos (`2` segundos).

Answer (score 2):

**Resposta baseada na fornecida por @VictorCarnaval**

Para obter imagem com o mesmo tamanho tens que arranjar um programa como o Photoshop e criar um gif com o mesmo tamanho que a maior (que neste caso é a animação de ataque).
Não podes simplesmente mudar o `height` e `width` do gif porque isso simplesmente vai esticar a imagem e não fica bem a transição.

Crie uma imagem com o mesmo tamanho para veres como fica e também acertei o `setTimeout` para a animação acabar no momento exacto.

```js
const pokemons = document.getElementsByClassName('pokemon');

function animatedPokemon() {
  const image = this;
  const src = image.dataset.src;
  const dataHover = image.dataset.hover;
  image.src = dataHover;

  setTimeout(function() {
    image.src = src
  }, 1530);
}

for (let i = 0; i < pokemons.length; i++) {
  pokemons[i].addEventListener('mouseover', animatedPokemon);
};
```

```css
img {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<img class="pokemon" src=https://i.ibb.co/DR0vdyN/Bulbasaur-XY-resized.gif" data-src="https://i.ibb.co/DR0vdyN/Bulbasaur-XY-resized.gif"
  data-hover="https://vignette.wikia.nocookie.net/pokemon/images/1/11/Bulbasaur_XY_AttackAnimation_Sprite.gif/revision/latest?cb=20141114181732">
```